# Java 8 stream, how to "break" in reduce or in collect without throwing runtime exception?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce, collect

This question have been asked in a context of `forEach`.

**Comment(after the answer was accepted): I accepted the answer of @nullpointer, but it is the right one only in the context of my code example, not in the general question about break-ability of reduce..**

The question:

But is there a way in `reduce` or in `collect` to "break" prematurely, without going through all the stream elements? (That means I need accumulate the state while iterating, so I use `reduce` or `collect`).

In short: I need iterate all elements of the stream (elements are integers and ordered from small to big), but look into 2 neighbor elements and compare them, if difference between them is greater than 1, I need "break" and stop "accumulate the state" and I need return the last passed element.

Variant to throw a `RuntimeException` and variant to pass external state - bad for me.

Code example with comments :

```
public class Solution {

public int solution(int[] A) {

    Supplier<int[]> supplier = new Supplier<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public int[] get() {
            //the array describes the accumulated state:
            //first element in the array , if set > 0, means  - the result is achieved, we can stop iterate over the rest elements
            //second element in the array will represent the "previous element" while iterating the stream
            return new int[]{0, 0};
        }
    };

    //the array in accumulator describes the accumulated state:
    //first element in the array , if set > 0, means  - the result is achieved, we can stop iterate over the rest elements
    //second element in the array will represent the "previous element" while iterating the stream
    ObjIntConsumer<int[]> accumulator = new ObjIntConsumer<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(int[] sett, int value) {
            if (sett[0] > 0) {
                ;//do nothing, result is set
            } else {
                if (sett[1] > 0) {//previous element exists
                    if (sett[1] + 1 < value) {
                        sett[0] = sett[1] + 1;
                    } else {
                        sett[1] = value;
                    }
                } else {
                    sett[1] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    BiConsumer<int[], int[]> combiner = new BiConsumer<int[], int[]>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(int[] sett1, int[] sett2) {
            System.out.println("Combiner is not used, we are in sequence");
        }
    };

    int result[] = Arrays.stream(A).sorted().filter(value -> value > 0).collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner);
    return result[0];
}


/**
 * We have an input array
 * We need order it, filter out all elements that <=0 (to have only positive)
 * We need find a first minimal integer that does not exist in the array
 * In this example it is 5
 * Because 4,6,16,32,67 positive integers array is having 5 like a minimum that not in the array (between 4 and 6)
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[]{-2, 4, 6, 16, -7, 0, 0, 0, 32, 67};
    Solution s = new Solution();
    System.out.println("The value is " + s.solution(a));
}
```

}

Comment: can you elaborate, what do you mean by *"accumulate the state" and I need return the last passed element*

Comment: Not all loops are best replaced with a stream. If you have behaviour like this it might be clearer as a loop (even if there is some way to make a Stream do what you want)

Comment: added code example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an array as input, seems to me you're looking for something like this :

```
int stateStream(int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length - 1)
            .filter(i -> arr[i + 1] - arr[i] > 1) // your condition
            .mapToObj(i -> arr[i])
            .findFirst() // first such occurrence
            .map(i -> i + 1) // to add 1 to the point where the cehck actually failed
            .orElse(0); // some default value
}
```

or from the scratch, while you convert it to a sorted and filtered value list as :

```
int stateStream(int[] arr) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .boxed().sorted()
            .filter(value -> value > 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size() - 1)
            .filter(i -> list.get(i + 1) - list.get(i) > 1)
            .mapToObj(list::get)
            .findFirst()
            .map(i -> i + 1)
            .orElse(0);
}
```

Comment: It is excellent, I learned a lot! But I can not accept that as an answer, because filter goes the whole round...(in 1-st example), in second example it is 2-d filter that I do not like. I mean , If positive array already created, I would prefer an answer, where we do not pass this array in full, just go to the first element that satisfies the condition,

Comment: @VladimirNabokov no it doesn't traverse the complete list, use of `findFirst()` helps in there(if that's what you meant)... the second implementation is the implementation that you can replace directly in your `main` method.

Comment: I must say that this is the right answer in the context of the code example. It solves the problem,but in the context of the initial question, "is reduce breakable?" it is not the answer, the answer is "it is unbreakable" (probably).

Answer (score 2):

The is no ways in streams API to `break`. You can throw an Exception, but it's really not a good idea.
But you are right - you can use reduce to find last "successed" element in collection

The list of ints:

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13);
```

Lets find the value of i-th element, where `element[i+1]-element[i] > 1` :

```
int result = integers.stream().reduce((i1,i2) -> (i2-i1) > 1 ? i1 : i2).get();
```

For this case result will be equals to 10.
And then you can just get the sublist of your common list;

```
integers.subList(0,integers.indexOf(result)+1).forEach(s-> System.out.println(s));
```

For cases of valid collection (when there are no elements with difference > 1) the `result` will be equals to the value of last element and sublist will be equals to list. So you can add some check to avoid `.subList` when it's not neccessary.

Example for reduce:

```
{1,2,3,5}
```

Step1:

```
i1 = 1; i2 = 2; -> reduce(), difference =1, so we reduce this pair to i2 (2)  -> new collection is{2,3,5}
```

Step2

```
i1 = 2; i2 = 3; -> reduce(), difference =1, so we reduce this pair to i2 (3)  -> new collection is{3,5}
```

Step3

```
i1 = 3; i2 = 5; -> reduce(), difference >1, so we reduce this pair to i1 (3)  -> new collection is {3} and it transforms to Optional<Integer>
```

Comment: i1 and i2 are placeholders of lambda expression. These are just a pair of nearest elements. Added some example to the answer.

Comment: So, in your example, we do pass all elements in the stream, till the end?
And I understand the logic(kinda), I just unable to find why that interpreted as a pair of neighbor elements...where all that formalized? I see the API used, but do you mean we always talk about pair of neighbors by default here:
Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator). I like your answer, but I can not tell it is a solution for the problem, however i learned something.

Comment: Yes, all elements, because, as I wrote earlier, in Streams there is no break condition.  The simpliest answer why it interprets i1 and i2 as neighbors elements: when you iterates over collection - you takes element by element. Right?  Here is ther same situation, except one moment - you takes pairs, pair by pair. So if your collection is sorted - it will be nearest by difference elements. Sorry, if I write not so clear, my explanation skills are quite weak :)

Comment: The API is Java 8 streams API. Documenentation - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html .

Comment: Danila, i1 and i2 are placeholders, but they are moving placeholders, i1 always contains the result of the reduction, and i2 is a next element. I just unable to comprehend, how they init i1 by 0 from beginning...at the start there is no default value for the reduction...

Comment: At the start - they are 0-th and 1-st element of collection

Comment: Danila, Ok... probably we have the common ground....with a bit of a taste of a magic :))

Comment: I will accept your answer for that "The is no ways in streams API to break", just later...may be some genius will provide a solution :) ..huge doubt..

Comment: If you want go deeeeeeeeper, you can check the source code of java.util.stream.ReduceOps class. But if I were you - I'd trust guys from Oracle, who wrote this API :)

Comment: I accepted the answer of @nullpointer, but it is the right one only in the context of my code example, not in the general question about break-ability of reduce..